# Selecting all data in MSSQL server for 17 tables

Tags: sql

I have 17 tables in MSSQL server. Is it possible to do a `Select *` and inner join all the tables together? Currently I have:

```
  SELECT Entry.ID, VehicleDetails.VIN, Entry.DateTimeCreated, VehicleOwnership.PurchaseDate
  FROM dbo.Entry
  INNER JOIN VehicleDetails ON Entry.ID=VehicleDetails.TransactionID
  INNER JOIN VehicleOwnership ON Entry.ID=VehicleOwnership.TransactionID
  where Entry.DateTimeCreated >= DATEADD(day,-365, GETDATE())
```

But could I do a `select *` instead of writing out every single table and header? Is there an easy way to do this when I am needing to grab all the data of every table?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want to select all columns from all 17 tables that will be `JOIN`ed together? You can `SELECT *` to get all columns from all tables but will have to `JOIN` each table explicitly

Comment: You can use SELECT * FROM, but you have to specify all the JOINs for all the tables, since MSSQL cannot know which fields to use.

Comment: So I think the problem is some tables have a seqID like 1, 2, 3 and there are multiple rows for that transactionID. I think that is why I am returning no data.

Comment: Sample data and expected result. A minimal example could help us a lot to understand what you need.

Comment: What helped me fix that issue was using left join instead of inner join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SELECT *` in a query with 3 joined tables will return all columns from all 3 tables. It is functionally the same as

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
INNER JOIN table3 t3
ON t1.ID = t3.ID
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton Show sample tables, sample data, and sample output in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [table alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to achieve this.

```
  SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
  FROM dbo.Entry A
  INNER JOIN VehicleDetails B ON A.ID=B.TransactionID
  INNER JOIN VehicleOwnership C ON A.ID=C.TransactionID
  where A.DateTimeCreated >= DATEADD(day,-365, GETDATE())
```

Comment: *FROM dbo.Entry A* While such aliasing is possible (honestly, I myself always use it), I don't think it will suit everyone, so it's better to stick with AS: `FROM dbo.Entry AS A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @joins NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
SELECT ' INNER JOIN' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) +'.TransactionID = ENTRY.ID'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE '' -- replace Like with your pattern
FOR XML PATH(''))

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)= CONCAT('SELECT * FROM Entry ', @joins)

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Bassicly if you have a pattern you can get all the table names and use to construct the join statements dynamicly. From what i can tell all your tables begin `Vechicle` so you could use this to chose those 17 tables.

Comment: @DavidBrierton I don't have your data but if you try to get a `LEFT JOIN` and use `TOP 1` you may be able to understand why this is happening. My guess is that a join from some table is not happening. So if an EntryID does not exist in any of the 17 tables you will get zero rows.

Comment: @DavidBrierton about your concern then if the multiple rows play a role. They don't they would simply create multiple rows with same data and the only difference would be on the customer data.